# Adding new ressource to Prestashop Webservice

Tags: php, api, prestashop

We are trying to add a new web-service resource from a module.

We can add it as a resource in the back-end, so it's visible. But we can't reach it on the URL:

http://example.com/api/quickpay/

We get 500 internal error. And with debug enabled:

```
Fatal error: Class 'QuickpayAPI' not found in /var/www/example.com/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php on line 479
```

We can access all the default web-service resources of course.

Here is the code for the module:

```
<?php
class QuickpayAPICore extends ObjectModel {


    public $exec_id;
    public $id_cart;
    public $trans_id;
    public $order_id;
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'quickpay_execution',
        'primary' => 'exec_id',
        'fields' => array(
            'exec_id' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'required' => true),
            'id_cart' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'required' => true),
            'trans_id' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
            'order_id' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING)
        )
    );
    protected $webserviceParameters = array();


}
?>

Placed: /modules/quickpay/override/classes

Filename: QuickpayAPI.php
```

The web-service:

```
<?php
class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore {
    public static function getResources(){
        $resources = parent::getResources();
        $resources['quickpay'] = array('description' => 'Quikpay Details', 'class' => 'QuickpayAPI');
        ksort($resources);
        return $resources;
    }


}
?>

Placed: /modules/quickpay/override/classes/webservice

Filename: WebserviceRequest.php
```

So why can't we reach the resource. We have added it to the API account.

What are we missing here to be able to access these resources via web-service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete class_index.php from ~/cache/ so that the new resources could be loaded.
Delete this file and refresh the page, it will work.